# How to change the language of the date selection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, date, datetime

I am using `WKWebview` of iOS, and there is a date selection in the html file. Right now, the part that selects the month is in `English`. But I want to change this to a different language. How can I change it?

```html
<input type="date" class="input" id="date1" >
```

@Piyush's answer does not fit my question.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use toLocaleString() method of Date.

Like this:

```js
var format = new Date().toLocaleString('fr-FR', { month: 'long' });

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = format;
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Here first argument "fr-FR" is the language code for various languages. You can find all available language codes [here](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm).

Comment: I have to be able to change the date.